# Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему должна стоять запятая перед И?

Tags: пунктуация

В тот день мы завтракали втроём(,) и, когда подали вишнёвый кисель, сестра капризно сказала, что десерт сегодня невкусный.

Я не понимаю, почему в первом случае должна стоять запятая. Мне кажется, «в тот день» является как бы общим второстепенным членом для «мы завтракали» и «сестра капризно сказала». Если я неправильно понял, объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(1)В тот день мы завтракали втроём,  и, когда (2) подали вишнёвый кисель, (3)*** сестра капризно сказала, (4) что десерт сегодня невкусный.

Здесь рассматриваются две разные временные ситуации. ***В тот день*** относится к предложению 1, а предложение 3 относится ко времени, указанному в придаточном предложении 2 (оно уточняет обстоятельство времени *в тот день*).

Это семантика. Что касается **структуры предложения,** то мы не можем соединить в одну фразу предложения 1 и 3 с помощью общего наречия, так как их разделяет предложение 2 (а именно в этом состоит смысл правила, позволяющего нам не ставить запятую в ССП).

Также обратим внимание **на разный вид глаголов**: завтракали (длительное действие) и сказала (завершенное действие).

Таким образом, чтобы применить это правило, **нужно учитывать разные факторы,** даже вид глаголов.

**Сравнить:** *В тот день родителей не было дома и мы завтракали втроем.*

Здесь нет запятой, наречие *в тот день* является общим второстепенным членом.